# How do I access folder using mount point?

Tags: permissions

I am trying to access a folder so I can copy  it into another partition.
I know the mount point `/mnt /uuid`, but cannot see it in my Ubuntu nautilus files.
(Long story irrelevant to this issue.)

I cannot find it using CLI ( `/home/...`) either.

Can I just "blindly" do copy (cp ?) /mnt/UUID... to destination?
Can I combine  "source " UUID with destination  folder name?
Can I bypass the security / user permissions? (sudo cp ...? )

A simple CLI example of a cp or equivalent command would be nice so I have a starting point.

Thanks

Comment: Better not to do anything "blindly". In Nautilus, if the partition is mounted, could be under "Other locations". In the CLI, first you should establish the source and destination *paths* you want to work with. You can use the commands `cd` and `ls`, to access a path and list the dirs/files in it. Use [tab completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) when needed. Don't use `sudo` unless completely necessary and understanding what you're doing, else you can harm your system badly.

Comment: Show how you mounted it. Show how you try to access it (command line preferred).

Comment: If you have access privilege, you can cp from to. If you are new to linux, you may need to add the user to sudoers give user some privilege. Use lsblk to check mount point, use ls -l to check if you have permission, then use cp or rsync with the help of Tab. this is an example:  mkdir /mnt/UUID/mydestination&& cp -a /path/to/myfolder/* /mnt/UUID/mydestination/